# How can I change Ubuntu server IP Address to the web address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, webserver, web

How can I change Ubuntu server IP Address to the web address? For example, the address that I need to access on the browser is 192.168.x.xxx. How can I change to dev.robi.local? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following into your hosts-file:

```
192.168.x.xxx    dev.robi.local
```

Then you can browse it. Otherwise you have to configure DNS for private network. I found this article (using BIND9 DNS server on Ubuntu 14), if you need guidance:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Note: You are talking about IP versus domain, and not IP versus a web address.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are accessing a remote server from your machine through the web browser.

To be able to access the server with **dev.robi.local** and not **192.168.x.xxx** you can edit your **hosts** file (**/etc/hosts**) and add the following entry:

```
 192.168.x.xxx      dev.robi.local
```

Comment: unfortunatelly it doesn't work :(

Comment: what happens when you ping the name dev.robi.local from your machine. What is the response you get?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that you can do for that other then installing and setting up local domain server is editing the `/etc/hosts/` and adding:

```
192.168.x.xxx    dev.robi.local
```

in there that will make your machine if its setup to first query local files in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` if you have files setup as first option in resolving parameters like for example:

```
hosts: files mymachines myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

Also make sure that you don't have additional entries in the `/etc/hosts/` with that same address if you do then make sure to put first close to the top of the file domain that you want to resolve to first.